# Jsoup POST payload как передать Json

Tags: android, jsoup

использую Jsoup в написание приложения для Android
не могу разобраться как передать Json при POST запросе на страницу

```
            String payload2 = "{'fields':{'car':['id']},{'offset':1}";
            Connection connect = connect(url1);
            connect.header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0");
            connect.header("Accept-Language", "ru");
            connect.ignoreContentType(true);
            connect.requestBody(payload2);
            //.header("Accept", "application/json")
            //.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            res = connect.execute();
```

такой формат выдает ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.andrew.gazadmin, PID: 13212
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a request body for HTTP method GET
        at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isFalse(Validate.java:64)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:733)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
        at com.example.andrew.gazadmin.GazAdmin$MyTask3.doInBackground(GazAdmin.java:133)
        at com.example.andrew.gazadmin.GazAdmin$MyTask3.doInBackground(GazAdmin.java:51)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

эмм,а зачем вам Jsoup? Это немного не то и имеет другие цели. Вам нужен [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jakson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) и т.д. Я предпочитаю первый варинт, так же лучше использовать связку с [Okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) и [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). А вот и отличная статья как всем этим [пользоваться](https://devcolibri.com/getting-started-with-retrofit-in-android/). Можно конечно делать всё по старинке, но на сколько я знаю Jsoup вам здесь не поможет, а только всё усложнит.